# bypass https to request non-secure link

Tags: angularjs, ssl, nginx

I have a bit of an issue that I can't seem to wrap my head around. The app/site is secured complete with a SSL Certificate, but we need to send an $http request with angular to a non-secured api end-point. The service does not offer a https solution and everytime we try sending the request, our server blocks it because it is not secured. Is there anyway to get around this? A way to "whitelist" the domain name or something?

Information: Server is running Nginx and the request is being made via $http angularjs.

Comment: You must [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) on your server in order to make a request to a defferent protocol, even if it's on the same domain

Comment: It's not the server that is blocking it, but the browser. Always post the complete and exact error when asking about an error. To make the previous comment clearer, it's the non-secued api endpoint that must enable CORS.

Comment: A different approach is to add a proxy endpoint to the secured API that will call the corresponding non-secure api  endpoint from the server (Using curl) and return the result to the client

Comment: So basically since I have no control over their API I have nothing that I can do on my end?